War movie where the protagonist philosophizes about Nature
Many years ago I watched a movie staged on the Pacific War (or Vietnam War, I cannot remember) where there was a soldier protagonist who kept talking to himself the whole piece, with deep thoughts, and sometimes it was as if he was talking to Nature. It was a very psychological movie. Since that time I am trying to find it again but since now entirely helplessly.

Posted a possible match, but do you remember anything else? Approximate year? Was it American? Do you remember any of the actors?

Thanks friend. The movie is exactly "The Thin Red Line".

Possibly Terrence Malick's The Thin Red Line from 1998 with Sean Penn, Nick Nolte and many others. From an online synopsis:

The opening sequence of The Thin Red Line finds two American soldiers AWOL among a group of South Pacific islanders. One of these soldiers, Private Witt (Jim Caviezel), supplies the movie its primary narrative voice, though the ensemble is so large and points of view alternate so frequently that nothing like a main character or "star" can truly be identified. Witt regularly rhapsodizes over the beauty of nature and the bliss of evading combat, though he is not so facile as to overlook the forces of conflict and antagonism that exist everywhere in the world, even outside the state of war. "What is this war in the heart of nature?" he apostrophizes in voice-over. "Why does nature vie with itself?"

Here's the trailer:




Thanks friend, this is exactly the movie I was looking for!
